# How to compute the dot product of every row of two different matrices fast using numpy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have two matrices and I want to take the row of the first matrix, transpose it and apply @ to the corresponding row of the second matrix to obtain a matrix. Do that for the number of rows in each. For example:

Matrix A = N x p

Matrix B = N x q

After operation I have N (p x q) matrices

An example to illustrate for the first row.

```
>>> x
array([[2, 1, 2],
       [4, 3, 1],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 1]])

>>> g
array([[2, 3],
        [3, 3],
        [1, 2],
        [2, 5]])
```

After first operation:

```
>>> x[0,:,np.newaxis] @ g[np.newaxis,0,:]
array([[4, 6],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 6]])
```

After second operation:

```
>>> x[1,:,np.newaxis] @ g[np.newaxis,1,:]
array([[12, 12],
       [ 9,  9],
       [ 3,  3]])
```

And so on, N times such that it would return N (p x q) matrices (Here 3 (3x2) matrices). How can this be done in Numpy with no loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
In [17]: x = np.array([[2, 1, 2],
    ...:        [4, 3, 1],
    ...:        [1, 2, 3],
    ...:        [1, 2, 1]])
    ...: g = np.array([[2, 3],
    ...:         [3, 3],
    ...:         [1, 2],
    ...:         [2, 5]])
In [18]: x.shape
Out[18]: (4, 3)
In [19]: g.shape
Out[19]: (4, 2)
```

With broadcasting, multiply a (4,3,1) with a (4,1,2) to produce (4,3,2):

```
In [20]: x[:,:,None]*g[:,None,:]
Out[20]: 
array([[[ 4,  6],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  6]],

       [[12, 12],
        [ 9,  9],
        [ 3,  3]],

       [[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  4],
        [ 3,  6]],

       [[ 2,  5],
        [ 4, 10],
        [ 2,  5]]])
In [21]: _.shape
Out[21]: (4, 3, 2)
```

`x[:,:,None]@g[:,None,:]` does the same thing, doing sum-of-products on the shared size 1 dimension.

Comment: I don't understand broadcasting very well when it comes to higher dimensions. How did you know that multiplying (4,3,1) with a (4,1,2) would produce (4,3,2)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
np.split(np.repeat(x.T, g.shape[1], axis=1) * g.ravel(), g.shape[0], axis=1)
```

It gives:

```
[array([[4, 6],
        [2, 3],
        [4, 6]]),
 array([[12, 12],
        [ 9,  9],
        [ 3,  3]]),
 array([[1, 2],
        [2, 4],
        [3, 6]]),
 array([[ 2,  5],
        [ 4, 10],
        [ 2,  5]])]
```